# itIngresar usuario default in tabla de mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

quiero crear un usuario default para la base de datos en mysql. Necesito que si y solo sí la tabla está vacía, inserte el usuario admin. Aquí dejo el código, no sé donde está mi error.

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
   user="root",
   password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()    
cursor1.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (Nombre text, Apellido text, Cedula bigint, Contraseña text)''')
insertar_usuario=('''INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Contraseña) Values ("Admin", "Baelca", 1776, "1234") HAVING COUNT(*)=0 ''' )
   
cursor1.execute(insertar_usuario)
conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

Edit:

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()    
cursor1.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (Nombre text, Apellido text, Cedula bigint, Contraseña text)''')
insertar_usuario=('''INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Contraseña) Values ("Admin", "Baelca", 1776, "12345")''' )
cantidad_registros = cursor1.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Usuarios ''')
if cantidad_registros == 0:
      cursor1.execute(insertar_usuario)
       
        
    
conn.commit() 
conn.close()
``
```

Comment: En esta respuesta del sitio en inglés hacen un truco para hacer un "insert condicional": https://stackoverflow.com/a/913929/12913664. Si no, lo que podés hacer es obtener la cantidad de filas de la tabla en una consulta dentro de Python poner un condicional tipo "if(numero_registros == 0): cursor.execute(...)" para que solo envíe el insert si no hay registros.

Comment: Epa, esa es una buena idea. Pensar fuera de mysql y usar python. Gracias @DanteS.

Comment: De nada! Pero diría que no tanto. En lo posible es mejor hacer todo dentro de MySql antes que en Python, ya que mysql es más rapido que Python.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar con python puedes crear una variable tipo booleano y haz esto
auxiliar = True

```
auxiliar = True
if auxiliar:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Contraseña) Values ("Admin", "Baelca", 1776, "1234") HAVING COUNT(*)=0 ''' )
    auxiliar = False
```

De esta forma la primera vez que ejecutes el código compilado se creará el primer registro y ya después no se ingresará de nuevo. En la práctica ya lo puedes comentar para que no te lo duplique a cada rato.
La solución que puedes usar con mysql sería

```
cantidad_registros = cursor.execute(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Usuarios)
```

Si la cantidad de registros es 0 lo insertas y si no pues que no haga nada

Comment: Hice lo segundo, pero me arroja error.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero el OP pide que se ingrese solo si la tabla está vacía, no cada vez que ejecute el código. Además, te faltan las comillas alrededor de la consulta sql en el segundo código.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).